# Pasar variable dentro de foreach

Tags: php

Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer esto, ando peleando con algo que no logro resolver, dentro de la generación de un PDF (usando fpdf) necesito pasar una variable dentro de un foreach pero no logro recibirla, paso a mostrar:

```
foreach ($companias_result as $compania) {
        $pdf->SetTextColor(128, 0, 128);
        $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
        $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20), 8, utf8_decode($compania["nombre"]), 0, 1, 'L');
        $pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
        $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20), 6, utf8_decode("Cuotas: {$compania["cuotas"]} / Refacturación: ". Refacturacion($compania["cuotas"])), 0, 1, 'L');
        foreach ($cotizaciones as $item) {
            if ($item->cotizacion_automotor->compania_id === $compania["id"]) {
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6 * 4, 6, "Cobertura", 1, 0, 'L');
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6, 6, "Costo total", 1, 0, 'C');
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6, 6, "Costo cuota", 1, 1, 'C');
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6 * 4, 6, utf8_decode($item->plan_descripcion), 1, 0, 'L');
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6, 6, "$ ".number_format($item->premio, 2), 1, 0, 'C');
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 8);
                $pdf->Cell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6, 6, "$ ".number_format($item->cuota, 2), 1, 1, 'C');
                $pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 8);
                $pdf->MultiCell(($pdf->GetPageWidth() - 20) / 6 * 4, 4, utf8_decode("{$item->detallecoberturarc} {$item->detallecoberturacasco} SUMA ASEGURADA: $ ".number_format($item->suma_asegurada, 2)), 1, 'L');
                $pdf->SetY($pdf->GetY() + 5);
            }
        }
    }
```

No logro recibir la variable $compania["id"] dentro del segundo foreach, cómo podría hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Estás comparando id con nombre, creo que por ahí es donde debe estar el problema.

Comment: ¿Has depurado algo para ver qué datos existen y qué estructura tienen? Si tienes problemas con `$compania`, haz un `var_dump($compania);` y revisa ese elemento. Es una norma básica de depuración que te ahorrará horas/días rompiéndote el coco.

Comment: Hola! Ahí corregí para que compare ID, un error de estar programando hasta largas horas de la noche jaja, de igual modo, sigo sin obtener el ID. Si realizo un echo $compania["id"] en el primer foreach me devuelve perfecto el valor, pero no logro pasarlo al segundo foreach. Gracias por las respuestas!